# Run *ONLY* `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` when power-button pressed, and not *ANYTHING* additional

Tags: kubuntu, scripts, suspend, power-management, acpi

I want to run a custom script when the power-button is pressed.

For a simple test, I put only a single line in `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`.

That line creates a file `it_ran.txt` in my home folder.

There is nothing else in `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`.

So, testing:

- I check the file `it_ran` doesn't exist.
- I press the power-button
- the computer suspends to ram
- I wake it back up
- the file `it_ran.txt` now exists

So `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` is running, but also something else.

That something else is putting the computer to sleep.

That will interfere with the custom script that I want to run.

How do I figure out what the something else is, and stop it?

Kubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Some BIOS can configure the power button to send ACPI signals.

Comment: Huh? The power-button *does* send an ACPI signal. According to `acpi_listen`. And of course that signal is the event that makes the `powerbtn.sh` script run. You mean... maybe the BIOS is *responding* to the ACPI signal...? >:?